# How to get the printer status using ESC/POS commands in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to check the status of a thermal printer using ESC/POS commands which is connected using USB in kotlin. The code I have implemented is as follows,

```
                    val usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0)
                    val usbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0)


                    val usbConnection = usbManager?.openDevice(usbDevice)
                    usbConnection?.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)

                    val data = byteArrayOf(0x10, 0x04, 0x04)


                    val d = usbConnection?.bulkTransfer(usbEndpoint, data, data.size, 500)
                  

                    val buffer = ByteArray(8)
                    val bytes = usbConnection?.bulkTransfer(usbInterface.getEndpoint(1), buffer, buffer.size, 500)
                    println("$bytes in  ${buffer.contentToString()}")
```

However according to the documentation and other materials on ESC/POS commands I should receive something like this 0b01101100 if there is no paper (refer: https://escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reliance_status.html). But what I am receiving in the above println statement is `[114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Is this the desired output or have I done anything wrong? A detailed guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information on the Pyramid ESC/POS page you are referring to is missing.
If you want to refer to the corresponding specifications of ESC/POS, this page is better.
[DLE EOT](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=118)

> - Each status consists of 1 byte, and the value is 0xx1xx10b.
>   The real time status can be differentiated by the bits 0, 1, 4, and 7 from other transmission data, except for data in block data (Header – NUL).

The printer reports 1 byte, and the question is not just the received data, but the entire buffer, including the unused area, so it's not the correct question.
Given the size of the data received, it would be correct to present only the first byte `114` in the question.

Since `114` is a decimal number, it is `01110010` when expressed as a binary number.

This value indicates that the roll paper end sensor bit `(5,6)` is `1` and there is no paper.
And the reason why the bits `(2,3)` of the roll paper near-end sensor are `0` is that the value `0` is notified because the near-end sensor has no meaning when there is no paper.

Comment: allright now i get it binaries should be counted from right to left such that the 5th and 6th bit is 11 -> which means no paper

Comment: so does the printer only responds with 1 byte at any given circumstances?

Comment: This command returns only 1 byte. Other commands may return multiple bytes. They depend on the specification of each command.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to prevent the printer from automatically printing the data when a new paper roll is inserted which was paused before due to insufficient paper?

Comment: That's usually not possible. If you really have such a desire, you will pay the vendor to customize it only for your company. And such a request would probably automatically discard the unfinished print request at the time the error occurred. [DLE ENQ](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=185) `n=2 : Recovers from a recoverable error after clearing the receive and print buffers.`

Comment: thanks a lot. Can this be achieved by disabling automatic line feed? Isn't there anything that could be done from the code level?

Comment: Even if it can be associated with the automatic line feed function, it is better not to think about it. Possibly unexpected strange situations can occur. In fact, I once worked for a company that makes POS terminals, and that company used printer vendors that customized the functions you wanted. It was realized with special firmware.

Comment: Are there any specific esc/pos commands to get printer information such as printer dpi and printer width?

Comment: It's probably here. [GS ( E <Function 6>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=234#gs_lparen_ce_fn06) Please check this site first. [TOP»POS › TECH.REFERENCE»ESC/POS COMMAND FOR TM PRINTER](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=2)